# I cannot get a value from a SQL server database with C++ Builder XE6

Tags: sql-server-2012, c++builder-xe6

I'm using c++ builder XE6 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and I'm connected in my database but when I try to select a column I get an error this is my code

```
 int Recuperer_Num_Verssioning_Sqlserver ()
{
TSQLConnection   *co = new TSQLConnection(NULL);
Base_SQLServer *sqls = new Base_SQLServer()  ;
bool bl = sqls->Connecter(co);
String tn =   ":BASE.:DBO.T_SOCIETE" ;
String col = "NUM_1" ;
String sqlstring = "SELECT " + col + " FROM " + tn +"";
int num ;

if (bl)
   {
        TSQLQuery *req = new TSQLQuery(NULL) ;
        req->SQLConnection = co ;
        req->SQL->Clear() ;
        req->SQL->Add(sqlstring) ;
        req->Open() ;
       //   req-> ExecSQL() ;
        if (!req ->Eof)
                {
                 num =  (int) req ->Fields->Fields[0]->AsCurrency ;

                }
                delete req ;     
                delete co ;
                delete sqls ;

                return num ;

   }

return -1 ;
```

}

After the opening I get the following error:
[SQL Error Code: 1087](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meALW.png)

Comment: Can you show a sample of what the `Select` statement would look like? Can you add a watch on the code and capture what `sqlstring` would look like before the `Open`?

Comment: Hey WEI_DBA i changed my code at top and i added my whole function i hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it was my SQL server 2012 user who hasn't have the right to get a result from the database.